# Material-UI v5 Datepicker - expand to the full width of its parent

Tags: material-ui

In Material-UI v4 the fullWidth prop could be passed to the Datepicker component. However, in v5 this prop is not listed in the component API. All css selectors for this component are non-deterministic and so I am unable to use the width css property. Is there any alternative that I have missed?

Answer (score 30):

This solution works:

```
 <DatePicker
    label="Date"
    slotProps={{ textField: { fullWidth: true } }}
  />
```

Answer (score 21):

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-v5-forked-fvc3er?file=/src/App.js

For both the `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` components in Material-UI v5, you need to set the `renderInput` prop. When using the `TextField` component as a rendering component, you can then use the `fullWidth` prop to expand to the width of its parent.

```
<DatePicker
  inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
  value={date}
  onChange={(value) => setDate(value)}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} fullWidth />}  <--- This right here
/>
```

Comment: Does not working for custom input or when u have nested custom popper

Comment: The `fullWidth` prop is only for a limited number of MUI components. Off the top of my head, at least `TextField` and `FormControl` have that prop. `Popper` does not have the `fullWidth` prop.

Comment: Whole picker is mess up. I've made fullwidth with ref from div element, and the textfield is wrapped inside div, talking about renderInput prop. On top of that I use date picker as placeholder whi open state to false, but the children property of the date picker is  actually custom popper with static date picker as child.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue with a CodePen or CodeSandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/69584676-open-dialog-instead-of-popper-in-desktop-mui-5-datepicker-m3muv?file=/demo.tsx
This is the code I've used and adapted for my need, but one thing i can't understand is, why staticdatepicker, can't work on it's own. The change around statick picker I've done, I've hide the toolbar. If u not wrap the static picker inside wrapper picker, the toolbar is mandatory and u can't replace custom textfield.

Comment: But, i've went to other direciton:
I;m using static date picker, but the textfield is on top of my static datePicker not part of renderInput, renderInput does not override anything. and even I'm using own clickaway listener amd i'm getting the width like this:  style={{ width: (inputWidth.current as any)?.clientWidth }}, the ref is attached to wrapper div around text field. probably I will share codepen in future days

Comment: Thank you for writing all of that info. I would like to continue to help you, but since you went another direction, we'll leave it at that.

Comment: I was searching for easy solution to eliminate MuiPaper class, as Autocomplete does with custom Popper prop, but that is not possible...

Answer (score 2):

For me the fullWidth Attribute didn't work. I am using the following versions: `"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.61",` and `"@mui/material": "^5.2.3"`.

My solution was simply exchange fullWidth width sx-styles like:

```
<DatePicker
  inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
  value={date}
  onChange={(value) => setDate(value)}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} sx={{width: '100%'}} />
```

Comment: Not working if u have custom popper, popper goes fullwidth as the client width. It's better approach to have div wrapper for the TextField and use ref to get the div width.

Answer (score 2):

A quick/temporary solution, without using the styled material UI

```
<DatePicker
sx={{ width: "100% " }}
className="MuiDayCalendar-header MuiDayCalendar-weekContainer" 
/>
```

In a css file:

```
.MuiDayCalendar-header {
    justify-content: space-around !important;
}

.MuiDayCalendar-weekContainer {
    justify-content: space-around !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the original intention of the thread was for devs like myself who just wanted to know how to customize the size of Material UI's `StaticDatePicker` component here is my [solution to this problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a9tjbu?file=package.json,src%2FApp.js).

In Material v5 we can use the [styled](https://styled-components.com/) to customize any components we like. I also chose to customize the `CalendarPicker` over the `StaticDatePicker` because it was easier to target the `.MuiCalendarPicker-root` class this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FormControl try this:

```
<FormControl
  className={className}
  variant="outlined"
  size="medium"
  required={required}
  error={hasError}
  disabled={disabled}
  fullWidth={fullWidth}
>
  <FormLabel htmlFor={name} style={{ marginBottom: 4 }}>
    {label}
  </FormLabel>
  <DateTimePicker minutesStep={15} disabled={disabled} format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm a" />
  {formHelperText && <FormHelperText>{formHelperText}</FormHelperText>}
</FormControl>
```

FormControl manage most of the states: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/form-control/

Answer (score -1):

Posting an answer for future reference since the above answers didn't work for me.

```
 renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}/>
```

You can change the value of span to increase or decrease length according to your need.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33461332)